# Prevent user (hacker) to view a string embedded in .NET desktop application

Tags: .net, security

I'm building an application that uses a secret key to communicate with REST API (via https).
I don't want user/hacker to discover that key and build his own application that could send false data to server. 
What are the best options to secure that 'string' inside application?

Here are the options I was thinking of:

1) Hard-code that string inside application and obfuscate assemblies.
I think that still some deobfuscation methods could decrypt this.

2) Pass it in app.config and encrypt on installation using that built-in .NET mechanism.
As I understand this, decryption key is stored somewhere inside windows and is not visible to users. Someone must have good system knowledge and hacking skills to retrieve this, yes?
If yes, then still when user downloads the installation package, he will be able to unzip it and see the secret key, right?

Do I have other options?

I know that there is no way of securing anything on client machine - there is no 100% security methods.

Bartek

Comment: Is authenticating the user an option?

Comment: User is authenticated anyway but still 'hacker' can build his own application that will use my REST API to send false data. It is crucial that WEB API consumes only real data generated only by my application.

Comment: Storing the secret key as part of the application is a bad idea. All copies of the application will share the same "secret" key. It is trivial to list all strings of a managed application. I.e. it is easy to extract the "secret" key from the binary.

Comment: Even obfuscated? Maybe it's not impossible but it's harder, yes?

Answer (score 2):

You have a secret that is outside of reach of an attacker : the user's password. The best you can do is

- make your REST key hard to replay (by not using it)
- make the calls tracable to a single user's session

Here is how you can mimic how browsers authenticate users. The OAuth2 client side web application flow is another example.

1. Ask for the user's password
2. Authenticate the user, probably using the same REST API you want to protect. By definition, this is not an authenticated call. Think of a login form, it is always public, on an HTTPS connection.
3. On the server side, generate a random number, called `nonce` and save it.
4. The user is still waiting for his logon, send him the `nonce`. That will be his very own REST *password*

Now, when your user clicks somewhere in your rich client that needs to make a REST call

1. Add a username-nonce pair to your REST call
2. On the server, when a REST call comes in, check that the username-nonce are valid
3. Call some sort of logoff on your API, and have the `nonce` expire after a while if not used.

The nonce itself should be hard to guess, a GUID will not do. The SHA-1 (or better) of a GUID is fine.

This is a lot of trouble ? True, but it is your only hope. Chances are your server architecture and client library already support some authentication scheme you can reuse, like HTTP BASIC auth.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the secret on the client. Store it and use it on a server.

If you send the secret to the client make sure you:
- encrypt it during transport and when stored on disk or in memory
- give it a (short) lifetime, so when it is decrypted or discovered it will no longer be valid.

You are correct: when someone is Admin on a system you cannot, ever trust the system to keep something safe.

If the user is not an Admin, you could use a certificate store or other special parts of the file system where only the system aand admins have access.

Comment: Thanks for answer but maybe I'll rephrase my question: how to secure rest web api to only accept requests from trusted client application - created by me? Any option I think of will allow discovering that secret key identifying a trusted app, deobfuscating code to see algorithm, and use this knowledge to create a false app that will introduce itself as trusted.

Comment: create certificates, hand them out to trusted users, only accept connection secured by these certificates. In other words: configure the server to only accept licensed clients.

Comment: That's a little bit how it will work. I just want to be sure that even if I do this, 'malicious' user can try to decompile assemblies, learn how it works, create their own app that signs connection with that certificate, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with a single secrete key is once the secrete is out then you can't really trust any data.

Any form of credentials coming from a device can be hacked.

So at a minimum I would have unique credentials from each device.
That way if you suspect bad data you can shut down those credentials and review any data associated with those credentials.

Credentials could be user/password, certificate, or even secrete key.
Could you set up the app to request a certificate.

Comment: This app will have couple of validation forms - login, session key, etc. Anyway I think the bottom line is that I can't prevent this...

Comment: You can't prevent it but you can sure shut is down.  E.G. invalidate a certificate.   Problem with a single secrete key is cannot shut down select devices.